# Batch file - output csv to different folders

Tags: batch-file

everything in my code is working fine except the last part.

I am wanting to output each text file to the folder with the same name. It is outputing the three text files into the one folder PentahoOutputs. However I am wanting to output it as the following:

folder system2.object2.assets contains file system2.object2.assets
folder system3.object3.assets contains file system3.object3.assets
folder system4.object4.assets contains file system4.object4.assets

```
@echo off SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET DELIMS=,
SET COMMAND=AddChange
SET EN=EN
SET ASSETS=Assets
SET DIREC = C:\Users\user.username\Documents\Training\BatchFiles\PentahoOutputs\
SET DELIMS2=.

FOR /D %%a IN (C:\Users\user.username\Documents\Training\BatchFiles\PentahoOutputs\*) DO ( SET subdirs=%%a 

result=!subdirs:~71,7!

result2=!subdirs:~79,7!

set "concats=!result!!delims!!result2!!DELIMS!!COMMAND!!DELIMS!!EN!"
echo !concats!

echo !CONCATS! >>C:\Users\user.username\Documents\Training\BatchFiles\PentahoOutputs\!result!!delims2!!result2!!delims2!!assets!.CSV

)

PAUSE>NUL
```

edit ********** below

changing the problem code to the following puts each of the three files in each of the three folders... however i want one file in each folder

```
for /d %%b in (C:\Users\usre.username\Documents\Training\BatchFiles\PentahoOutputs\*) DO ( echo !CONCATS! >>%%b\!result!!delims2!!result2!!delims2!!assets!.csv )
```

Comment: In `SET DIREC = `, remove the _spaces_ around the `=` sign as they become part of the variable name and value otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your posted code - given aschipfl's change as noted (although you don't attempt to use `direc`)

Your posted code has been mangled in an attempt, I assume, to disguise usernames. It also appears that you've cut down the actual code to show only the relevant section. This is good and understandable (but your edit has a glaring typo in the code - which is why you should cut-and-paste as far as possible.)

So - the `setlocal` following the `@echo off` must be separated by a `&` command-concatenator or be (my preference) on a separate line.

Within your `for ... %%a ...` block, you've removed the required `set` keyword for `result*`.

The fixed values you've used for substringing don't suit the changes you've made to the pathname, so the result in `result` is (eg) "tem3.ob"

If a value does not change within a block (like `delims`) then it's probably best to use `%delims%` - `result` changes, so you'd use `!result!` not `%result%`. `!delims!` also works, of course - but using the delayed-expansion form primes the reader to believe it's going to vary. (opinion)

'tis best with a string assignment to use `set "var=value"` as the quotes ensure that stray trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned. You only ever need to have that happen once...

OK - here's a revision

```dos
@echo OFF
SetLocal
SET DELIMS=,
SET COMMAND=AddChange
SET EN=EN
SET ASSETS=Assets
SET DIREC=U:\Users\user.username\Documents\Training\BatchFiles\PentahoOutputs\
SET DELIMS2=.

FOR /D %%a IN (%direc%*) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%p IN ("%%~nxa") DO IF /i "%%r"=="%assets%" (
  echo %%p%delims%%%q%DELIMS%%COMMAND%%DELIMS%%EN%
  echo %%p%delims%%%q%DELIMS%%COMMAND%%DELIMS%%EN% >> %%a\%%~na.CSV
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that I've used `U:` for the test directory (it's a ramdrive on my machine)

Given the outer loop, `%%a` is assigned the full pathname to the directory.

Since you imply that your target directorynames are `system2.object2.assets` then `%%~nxa` (the Name and eXtension of %%a) conveniently holds this string. Parsing that using delims of `.` and selecting the first 3 tokens would assign `system2` to `%%p`, `object2` to `%%q` and `assets` to `%%r` This avoids the substringing problem and permits `system` and `object` to be any length - not just 7.

The `if` statement ensures that the main block for `for...%%p` is only executed for directories found which fit *.*.asset (`/i` makes the `if` case-insensitive)

The required line can then be constructed from the metavariables and constants, as can the destination filename, so the `enabledelayedexpansion` is not required.

Comment: this works, thank you and thanks for the explanations